# Awk printing matched line and Nth following line using c&&!--c

Tags: regex, awk, formatting

So, I have got my head around the famous "c&&!--c".. Although maybe not.

When using Awk to print the Nth line after a matched line, I'd like to print the Nth line, a space, then the matched line, on the same output line.

For example, given the file tmpfile.txt;

```
blar
Matchme
blar
XXXX
blar
```

I'd like to get the following

```
XXXX Matchme
```

But.. Using

`awk 'c&&!--c  ; /Matchme/ {c=2} ; /Matchme/' tmpfile.txt`

gives

```
Matchme
XXXX
```

Adding a printf doesn't help..

`awk 'c&&!--c  ; /Matchme/ {c=2} ; /Matchme/ {printf $0}' tmpfile.txt`

gives

```
MatchmeXXXX
```

Can anyone explain why the first pattern/action is being printed last?

Thanks

gary_s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
awk 'c&&!--c {print $0,f} /Matchme/ {c=2;f=$0}' file
XXXX Matchme
```

It saves the `pattern` line to variable `f`, then after `2` lines print current line and `f`

---

```
awk 'c&&!--c  ; /Matchme/ {c=2} ; /Matchme/ {printf $0}'
```

This part `/Matchme/ {printf $0}` is true at the moment it finds the pattern, so it will print it.
Then after two line it will print `XXXX`

Comment: The first script is correct but don't use that second script as it unnecessarily duplicates the condition, has a spurious semi-colon and would fail in surprising ways if the input file contained printf formatting characters in the right places (always use `printf "%s", $0`, not `printf $0`).

Comment: blimey. quick response appreciated, and it works. Explanation helped me to understand what seemed like crazy behaviour. Thanks Jotne

Comment: I echo your thoughts @Ed Morton. Jotne was simply repeating my own terrible attempt at fixing the script, so I concur, no one should use  it. or even look at it. Oh, and I'll be using the %s trick in future. Cheers

Comment: @EdMorton For the second script I just trying to explain Garys_s post.

Comment: @Jotne ah, that explains it, I thought it was odd that you'd come up with something like that! gary_s - `"%s"` isn't a trick, it's just the format string that's the required by `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

This produces the output that you want:

```
$ awk 'c && !--c {print $0, s} /Matchme/ {s=$1; c=2}' file
XXXX Matchme
```

The `c` check at the start prevents the first line from being printed (because at the start of the program `c` would evaluate to 0). As pointed out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25900298/awk-printing-matched-line-and-nth-following-line-using-c-c/25900460#comment40539192_25900460) (thanks Ed), it also means that the right hand side of the `&&` will only be evaluated when `c` is positive. When /Matchme/ is matched, the value of the first column is stored and the countdown from 2 begins. `!--c` is only true when `c` is 0, so the `print` happens two lines after the match.

Comment: +1 for getting there first. The `c` check is mostly to ensure that `--c` doesn't continue to get evaluated after `c` reaches zero after that pattern is found. I used to use the simpler `--c>=0` but then realized that on a HUGE file `--c` might conceivably wrap around and appear to be positive again so I changed it to `c&&--c` etc. instead just to make sure that can't happen.

Comment: Kudos for the fast response and a working solution. I gave the tick to Jotne because his explanation helped me understand a little more. But thanks Tom

Comment: Your post is 100% copy of mine, no single difference.

Comment: @Jotne actually I wrote my answer independently (and they are _slightly_ different), although it's no surprise that they have turned out to be almost identical as they both use `c&&!--c`, which was part of the question.